# "Speaking English or to speak English?"

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

What is the difference between these two sentences? I guess the first one is correct but what about the second one? In what circumstances can we use it?

1. "Speaking English is not so easy."
2. "To speak English is not so easy."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Speaking English` is the present form of a person doing it, and defines a general situation in this case.
`To speak english` is tenseless and has no adjectives: It's not bound to a person, or something that speaks in general, so `To speak english is not easy` is wrong

That's how I would define it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "To speak English I use a dictionary" sounds correct?

Comment: You would do "I use a dictionary to speak english". Before the "to speak" you say what you do. "I use a calculator to do math" for example. If you say that part afterwards, you'd replace to with for, and use the -ing  form of the verb: "For speaking english I use a dictionary"

Comment: Thank you, it was very useful :)

Comment: I would dispute the assertion that "To speak English is not easy" is incorrect. You can refer to an action by using _either_ a participle (speaking) _or_ an infinitive (to speak). There is no great difference in meaning.